# Next js showing this error when creating a file name 'middleware' in the root directory. Otherwise the app runs fine

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

error - Error [TypeError]: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
at ../../node_modules/.pnpm/undici@5.11.0/node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/file.js (evalmachine.:5724:19)
at __require (evalmachine.:14:50)
at ../../node_modules/.pnpm/undici@5.11.0/node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/formdata.js (evalmachine.:5881:49)
at __require (evalmachine.:14:50)
at ../../node_modules/.pnpm/undici@5.11.0/node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/body.js (evalmachine.:6094:35)
at __require (evalmachine.:14:50)
at ../../node_modules/.pnpm/undici@5.11.0/node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/response.js (evalmachine.:6510:49)
at __require (evalmachine.:14:50)
at  (evalmachine.:11635:30)
at requireFn (file://D:\Nishad@b2g\Frontends\texsupplier-frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\edge-runtime\index.js:1:7079) {
middleware: true

middleware code

```
export default function middleware(req){
    
    const cookies = parseCookies()
    let verify =  cookies.token
    let url =  req.url

    if(url.includes('/profile')){
        NextResponse.redirect('http://localhost:3000')
    }
}
```

Comment: could you paste the middleware code

Comment: I have added my middleware code.

Comment: I also have this issue. Have found any solution?